# europecv missing character in font problem

Tags: europecv

I'm trying to compile an CV with europecv. Unfortunately this is no longer working as expected. I last tried it in late 2019 which works fine.
Using this example...

```
\documentclass[utf8, a4paper, 10pt, helvetica, narrow, flagWB, booktabs, totpages, german]{europecv}
\usepackage{graphicx}                        % Required to draw the flag
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{babel}

% Commands europecv

\ecvLogoWidth{12mm}                  % Size logo europass
%\ecvLeftColumnWidth{4cm}            % Size of column and vertical line (different from standard)
%\ecvfootnote{footnote}              % Foot notes
\ecvname{\textsc{Surname}, First Name}

% Personal picture

\ecvbeforepicture{\raggedleft}
\ecvpicture[height=1in]{namefile_pic}   % File picture without extension                 
\ecvafterpicture{\ecvspace{-2.5cm} }

% Address

\ecvaddress{Address first line\\& Address second line\\& City, State}

% Telephone 

\ecvtelephone{+44 (0) 123 4567}
%\ecvfax{+39 01234567}

\ecvemail{john@someserver}

% Other personal info

\ecvnationality{Nationality}
\ecvdateofbirth{01/01/1900}
\ecvgender{Male}

\begin{document}

% Begin europecv environment

\begin{europecv}

\ecvpersonalinfo        % Print personal info in preamble

\ecvitem{}{}        % 1 free line - \ecvitem{}{} adds elements to a section
%\ecvsection{}      % \ecvsection{} adds sections

\ecvitem{\large\textbf{Desired employment / Occupational field} }{\Large\textbf{Dream job} }  % desired job

% Sections

% School

\ecvsection{Education and training}

\ecvitem{Dates}{From September 1900 to August 1905}\\
\ecvitem{Title of qualification awarded}{Name of the\\& degree}\\
\ecvitem{Principal subjects/occupational skills covered}{Learned skills}\\
\ecvitem{Name and type of organisation providing education and training}{My University\\&
Address\\&
City\\& Nation\\&
Post code\\&
Tel. +44 (0) 123 45678 23}\\
\ecvitem{Level in national or international classification}{Level of degree}\\

%\pagebreak{}

% Single course

\ecvitem{Dates}{August 2013}
\ecvitem{Title of qualification awarded}{Name of certification}
\ecvitem{Principal subjects/occupational skills covered}{Skills of certification}
\ecvitem{Name and type of organisation providing education and training}{Institution}\\

% Last working experience

\ecvsection{Work Experience}
\ecvitem{Dates}{From June 1957 to February 1987}\\
\ecvitem{Occupation or position held}{Name of the job}\\
\ecvitem{Main activities and responsibilities}{Activities during \\& this job}
\ecvitem{Name and address of employer}{Name of employer\\&
Employer address\\&
Second line\\& City\\& Nation\\&
Tel. +39 (0) 1234 5678}\\
\ecvitem{Type of business or sector}{Business}\\

% Volunteer experiences

\ecvsection{Volunteer Experience}

\ecvitem{Dates}{From August 2000 to present}\\
\ecvitem{Occupation or position held}{First Aider}\\
\ecvitem{Main activities and responsibilities}{Activities}
\ecvitem{Name and address of employer}{Name\\&
Address\\&
City\\& Post code\\&
Nation\\&
Tel. +44 (0) 1234 7654}\\
\ecvitem{Type of business or sector}{Business}\\

% Personal competences

\ecvsection{Personal skills and competences}

% Languages

% Mothertongue

\ecvmothertongue[10pt]{Italian}\\       % 10pt leave a one-char line space before the text

% Table for common language evaluation

\ecvlanguageheader{(*)}
\ecvlanguage{English}{\ecvCOne}{\ecvCOne}{\ecvCOne}{\ecvCOne}{\ecvCOne}          % second language and levels
      % Language levels A1 - A2 - B1 - B2 - C1 - C2 from basic to advanced.
      % in this package are \ecv + A, B or C and the sub-level in letters (One or Two)
\ecvlanguage{French}{\ecvBTwo}{\ecvBTwo}{\ecvBTwo}{\ecvBTwo}{\ecvBTwo}       % third
\ecvlastlanguage{Russian}{\ecvAOne}{\ecvATwo}{\ecvBOne}{\ecvCTwo}{\ecvBTwo}     % last language

\ecvlanguagefooter{(*)}\\

% Social skills

\ecvitem{Social skills and competences}{- First social skill;\\& - Second social skill}\\

% Technical skills

\ecvitem{Technical skills and competences}{- First technical skill;\\& - Second technical skill}\\

% Computer skills

\ecvitem{Computer skills and competences}{- First skill;\\& - Second}\\

% Other skills

\ecvitem{Other skills and competences}{- First otherskill}\\

% Driving Licence

\ecvitem{Driving licence(s)}{Category and Type}\\

% Annexes

\ecvsection{Annexes}
\ecvitem{}{On request:}
\ecvitem{}{Birth certificate}
\ecvitem{}{Passport}
\ecvitem{}{Driving licence}
\ecvitem{}{Criminal record certificate}
\ecvitem{}{University study plan}
\ecvitem{}{}

% Disclaimer

\ecvsection{Disclaimer}
\ecvitem{}{This informations may be used for all purposes permitted by law and under the Data Protection Act 1998.\\&
Autorizzo l'utilizzo dei dati personali contenuti nel presente curriculum ai sensi del D.Lgs. 196/2003 e s.m.i. (Codice in materia di protezione dei dati personali)}

\end{europecv}
\end{document}
```

... I receive the following error message (using TexLive 2019):

```
Line 112: No declaration for shape OT1/phv/mc/sl. \ecvlanguageheader{(*)}
...
Line 119: No declaration for shape OT1/phv/mc/sl. \ecvlanguagefooter{(*)}
```

This is a Demo CV from the web which throws the same error. In my real CV, I'm using german language.
It seems that specific characters are missing.
[image: Missing German Umlauts]

The logfile shows the following error:

```
! No declaration for shape T1/phv/mc/sl.
sub@sfcnt ...e forspace shapespace mandatory@arg }
                                                  error@fontshape else #1{Fo...
l.38 \ecvlanguageheader{(*)}

(That was another \errmessage.)

**Missing character: There is no ä in font cmr10!**
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 38.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 40.
! No declaration for shape T1/phv/mc/sl.
sub@sfcnt ...e forspace shapespace mandatory@arg }
                                                  error@fontshape else #1{Fo...
```

Does anyone has an idea whats going wrong here/how can I solve this??

Comment: My header is this one:
```
\documentclass[utf8, a4paper, 10pt, helvetica, narrow, flagWB, booktabs, totpages, german]{europecv}
\usepackage{graphicx}                        % Required to draw the flag
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{babel}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is the helvet package. Its fd-files should be adapted to the changes in latex but that didn't happened yet. See https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/299 
As a work-around: Don't use the narrow option. And add this to your preamble:

```
\documentclass[utf8, a4paper, 10pt,helvetica,flagWB, booktabs, totpages, german]{europecv}

\makeatletter
\input{ot1phv.fd} 
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{phv}{c}{it}{<->ssub * phv/c/sl}{} %error without this
\makeatother
\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{md}{c}
\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{bc}
\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[sf]{md}{c}
\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[sf]{bf}{bc}


\begin{document}
\textit{abc}
\end{document}
```

If you are using T1-encoding change ot1/OT1 to t1/T1.

Comment: Hi Ulrike, awesome. Thanks you so much.